# Pass arguments into JButton ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm looking for a way to pass a variable or string or anything into an anonymous actionlistener ( or explicit actionlistener ) for a JButton. Here is what I have:

```
public class Tool {
...
  public static void addDialog() {
    JButton addButton = new JButton( "Add" );
    JTextField entry = new JTextField( "Entry Text", 20 );
    ...
    addButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener( ) {
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
      {
        System.out.println( entry.getText() );
      }
    });
  ...
  }
}
```

Right now I just declare `entry` to be a global variable, but I hate that way of making this work. Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Create a class that implements the `ActionListener` interface.
2. Provide a constructor that has a `JTextField` argument.

---

## Example -

```
class Foo implements ActionListener{
    private final JTextField textField;

    Foo(final JTextField textField){
        super();
        this.textField = textField;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

---

Problem?

Comment: Problem: Java newb. Thanks for the info, worked great and gave a better understanding of how it all tied together.

Comment: Still, I had the same problem and got this as a usefull answare.

Answer (score 3):

2 ways

1. make `entry` `final` so it can be accessed in the anonymous class

   ```
   public static void addDialog() {
       JButton addButton = new JButton( "Add" );
       final JTextField entry = new JTextField( "Entry Text", 20 );
       ...
       addButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener( ) {
         public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
         {
           System.out.println( entry.getText() );
         }
       });
     ...
     }
   ```
2. make `entry` a field

   ```
   JTextField entry;
   public static void addDialog() {
       JButton addButton = new JButton( "Add" );
       entry = new JTextField( "Entry Text", 20 );
       ...
       addButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener( ) {
         public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
         {
           System.out.println( entry.getText() );
         }
       });
     ...
     }
   ```

Comment: 2) is basically how I was getting it to work. I haven't tried 1) yet, but I did get it to work with mre's suggestion. Haven't used `final` enough yet to really grasp the usage I guess, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe better in this case to use Action and AbstractAction, where you could do that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

From the code I see here, entry is NOT a global variable. It's a local variable in the addDialog() method.. Did I misunderstand you?

If you declare the variable locally as final, then the listener will be able to access it.

```java
    final JTextField entry = new JTextField( "Entry Text", 20 );
    ...
    addButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener( ) {
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
      {
        System.out.println( entry.getText() );
      }
    });
  ...
```

Comment: I wrote this snippet as a local so it would work, what I was meaning was that this is how I _wanted_ it to work. The way I was using it, it was global.